# Why is there space between my string after concatenation with PHP form?

Tags: php, forms, post, concatenation

This is really bizarre because I checked that the two strings which I have concatenate does not have a space between them in the HTML source code. However, when PHP parse the text in my `update.php` file, it returns `string1 string2` instead of `string1string2` which is the expected output.

What went wrong?

**Update.php**

```
<?php

    $string1 = $_POST['string1'];
    $string2 = $_POST['string2'];
    $filename = str_replace(" ", "", substr($string1, 14))
        . str_replace(" ", "", substr($string2, 11));


    echo $filename;
?>

$_POST['string1'] = Exchange Name: Osaka;
$_POST['string2'] = Stock Name: 20;
```

Comment: what are the values for $_POST["string1"] and 2

Comment: Are you sure the space is a space, and not a tab or newline character?

Comment: @HankyPanky: Added the values.

Comment: @Michael: How may I check whether the space is a space and not a tab or newline character? please advise.

Comment: @TingPing My guess is that you're checking the output in a browser. What you want to do is to view the source code of the output so it's not html-formatted. Pass an array of all possible character to `str_replace` instead of just space, e.g. `str_replace(array(' ', '\n', '\t'), '', $subject);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$string1 = "Exchange Name: Osaka";
$string2 = "Stock Name: 20";
$pattern = '/[\W]/i'; // you can add extra conditions to handle other chars as well
$replacement = "";

echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string1)
    . preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string2);
```

Comment: Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier '\' in D:\wamp\www\update.php on line 11

Comment: Remove the slash in the middle. Should be `$pattern = '/\n\t/i';`

Answer (score 2):

Possibly try using trim instead of replace.

```
    trim(substr($string1,14));
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: trim would remove spaces only from ends, not if they are in any other position

Answer (score 1):

After populating filename, You can use

```
$filename = str_replace(" ", "", $filename);
```

But this is not a proper solution considering we didnt yet figure out where the issue lies, it is just a fix. So first find the issue so you know why it is happening

Then somehow you are getting new line characters from the form which posted these values. Try this

```
$filename = str_replace("\r", "", $filename);
$filename = str_replace("\n", "", $filename);
```

Comment: I just ran your code and it seems to work as you expect it to. You sure its showing a space for you?

Comment: I am running on windows. I am not sure whether that will affect the result?

Comment: view source of the output, see if shows with a space or a newline? for me your code outputs Osaka20

Comment: The source output shows that the two strings are separated by a new line. Hmm, seems like the 'space' problem is really a newline issue. How may i get rid of that new line?

Comment: check update. you can consolidate those 2 replaces in one and just replace "\r\n"

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using the following:

```
echo str_replace(PHP_EOL, '', $filename);
```